# How to save history of my browser in windows phone?

Tags: browser, windows-phone, browser-history

I just made my new app "Faster browser", over implemented all the settings but I'm unable to code on how to create a page to save history in it. Can anyone please help me or explain me with your code, so that I can understand it and copy-paste it in my app easily.

Comment: I don't know the specifics of Windows app programming, but you could just capture the link when the person presses the 'Go' button next to the URL bar, and then add that to an array. Display in a new 'History' window.

Comment: Can you please elaborate it with some code..!! I've no idea about capturing textbox(url bar. Adress) and saving it in another page as history. I'm using windows phone RT template.

Comment: As I have said, I do not know Windows app programming, I have only done programming on Android. Somebody else should be able to add code once they get here. Hold tight.

Comment: Thank you for the idea of capturing link from url box, it may works to some extent... But if user browses through the webview directly its not catching the url....so its one of the drawback

Comment: You can set WebView to display logs, so you could jot that down. Dunno how in Windows. Someone else really should look at this question.